# Awk print single element of array

Tags: awk

This ought to be ridiculously easy.  I simply want to print a single element of an array.  However, all I get from a command like `print arr[1]` is an empty line.

Here is my entire bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
find -X $1 -type f | 
xargs md5 | 
awk '

NF == 4 {
     md5[$4]++;
     files[$2]++;
}

END {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
    for (j = i + 1; j <= NF; j++)
        if (md5[i] == md5[j]) {
            print "These are duplicates: "
            print files[j+1]
            print files[i]
        }

'

exit 0
```

It is a very simply duplicate file finder.  The problematic part is in the END{} statement within awk.

This just gives me a bunch of "These are duplicates: " with empty lines after them.  I know that the information is available, because I add this to END{}: `for (x in arr); print x` and it flawlessly prints every element in arr, as expected.

I must be doing something very silly.

Comment: Are you sure your arrays are numerically indexed?

Comment: I thought that is how all awk arrays work.  If they are not numerically indexed, how can I reference individual elements?

Comment: You can see my entire code above, so you can tell that I have done nothing special to index my array elements.  If that does not occur automatically, then I will need to introduce that somehow.

Comment: You seem to be assigning your arrays with fields `$4` and `$2` as indexes. What are these? Don't have a shell handy. :)

Comment: Oh.  Yes, that is a problem.  $2 is file paths and $4 is MD5 sums.  Instead of making those indices, I would like to make those the elements of the array.

Comment: Oh I see what you were getting at. What you're doing is assigning the _values_ as indices, which from a cursory search seems to be a practice in `awk`. You could just create a couple of variables (one for each array) in `BEGIN` and then increment those, and assign like `md5[index++] = $4`, for example.

Comment: Ah!  Thank you, that was indeed the problem.  My understanding of awk arrays was fundamentally flawed.

Comment: You must omit the semicolon at "for (x in arr); print x" or just will print the "last" element in arr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're currently doing is assigning the values you want to save as the indices of the two arrays, which seems to be common from code examples in `awk`. However, that's usually used in conjunction with the `for (x in y)` syntax. To fix your code, the way that comes to mind to fix what you're doing is to modify your `awk` bit like so:

```
BEGIN {
    md5idx = 0;
    filesidx = 0;
}
```

And then change:

```
NF == 4 {
    md5[md5idx++] = $4;
    files[filesidx++] = $2;
}
```

That should about do it, I think, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: I made another, very silly but unrelated mistake: I should have i and j incremented until they are <= length(md5)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using variables, you can also use `NR` which contains `line number` as an index to store field values in to your arrays.

```
NF == 4 {
     md5[NR]=$4;
     files[NR]=$2;
}
```

and then in your `END` portion, you can use, something like `for (i=1;i<=NR;i++}`. Since, in `END statement` you will always have the value of `NR` as the last line number, you don't need to use an arbitrary number or even the `length function` of `awk` to find the length of an array.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to find a standard `md5` as opposed to my own home-brew version, but the example output from a version on MacOS X 10.7.2 is:

```
$ /sbin/md5 $(which -a md5)
MD5 (./md5) = 57f49e1c53ca7875fe63a33958ab0b0b
MD5 (/Users/jleffler/bin/md5) = 57f49e1c53ca7875fe63a33958ab0b0b
MD5 (/sbin/md5) = dd00b1dc4dd11c8443a70b5d33e0cade
$
```

Assuming that the output of `md5` is a hash in column 4 and a file name in column 2 with the parentheses around the name not mattering, and also assuming that the names do not contain any spaces (because spaces in the file name will mess up the column numbering), then you probably want something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
find -X "${@:-'.'}" -type f | 
xargs /sbin/md5 | 
awk '
NF == 4 {
     if (file[$4] != "") printf "Duplicate: MD5 %s - %s & %s\n", $4, file[$4], $2;
     else file[$4] = $2;
}'

exit 0
```

Example output:

```
Duplicate: MD5 57f49e1c53ca7875fe63a33958ab0b0b - (./md5) & (/Users/jleffler/bin/md5)
```

This identifies duplicate MD5 values as it goes.  If there is no entry in the (associative) array `file` for the given MD5 hash, then an entry is created with the file's name.  If there is an entry, then the MD5 value and the two file names are printed; you can debate the format, which might be better spread over three lines than cramped onto one.

The `"${@:-'.'}"` notation means 'use the command line arguments if there are any; otherwise, use `.` (the current directory)'.  This seems likely to be more usable than using the first argument (only) and failing if no argument is supplied.